# Node.js Controller file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, controller

```
exports.getUsers = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const features = new APIFeatures(User.find(), req.query)
    .filter()
    .sort()
    .limitFields()
    .paginate();

  const users = await features.query;
  res.status(200).json({
    status: true,
    results: users.length,
    data: users,
  });
});
```

Please I need someone to explain this piece of code to me. What those lines mean and do?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This all lines are the single request to the database

CatchAsync is a wrapper to catch errors and handle them in case some bad happened during the call

APIFeatures is an instance of a custom class that passes method and a query to the constructor and it returns an object with predefined pipeline in it.
filter, sort,limitedFields and paginate are methods that called inside that class to build a pipeline.

then you wait the execution of this pipeline and get users back.

Then you send a response in json format to the frontend I guess.

To explain more it is nice to have more context.